# Recalculating distance matrix

Tags: r, distance

I’ve got a large input matrix (4000x10000). I use `dist()` to calculate the Euclidean distance matrix for it (it takes about 5 hours).
I need to calculate the distance matrix for the "same" matrix with an additional row (for a 4001x10000 matrix). What is the fastest way to determine the distance matrix without recalculating the whole matrix?

Comment: Do you know how to do it but not in R or do you not know how to do it?

Comment: Is the extra row an extra point or an extra variable/dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume your extra row means an extra point. If it means an extra variable/dimension, it will call for a different answer.

First of all, for euclidean distance of matrices, I'd recommend the `rdist` function from the `fields` package. It is written in Fortran and is a lot faster than the `dist` function. It returns a `matrix` instead of a `dist` object, but you can always go from one to the other using `as.matrix` and `as.dist`.

Here is (smaller than yours) sample data

```
num.points <- 400
num.vars   <- 1000
original.points <- matrix(runif(num.points * num.vars),
                          nrow = num.points, ncol = num.vars)
```

and the distance matrix you already computed:

```
d0 <- rdist(original.points)
```

For the extra point(s), you only need to compute the distances among the extra points and the distances between the extra points and the original points. I will use two extra points to show that the solution is general to any number of extra points:

```
extra.points <- matrix(runif(2 * num.vars), nrow = 2)
inner.dist   <- rdist(extra.points)
outer.dist   <- rdist(extra.points, original.points)
```

so you can bind them to your bigger distance matrix:

```
d1 <- rbind(cbind(d0, t(outer.dist)),
            cbind(outer.dist, inner.dist))
```

Let's check that it matches what a full, long rerun would have produced:

```
d2 <- rdist(rbind(original.points, extra.points))

identical(d1, d2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I tried to use:  
mydist<-dist(original.points)  
mydist <- as.matrix(mydist)  
euc.dist<-function(x){  
sqrt(sum((extra.point - x) ^ 2))  
}  
extra.dist<-apply(original.points, 1, euc.dist)
rbind(mydist, extra.dist)  

my problem was with binding the extra row to an object of class "dist"

Comment: A distance matrix is a square matrix. You are only adding one row at the end, you should also add a column at the end, and the value in the bottom right should be zero (the distance between the extra point and itself). But please read my solution...