# Optimizing speed of nearest search function in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I'm trying to make this function faster (ideally with RcppAmadillo or some other alternative). *myfun* takes a matrix, *mat*, that can get quite large, but is always two columns. *myfun* finds the closest rows for each row in the matrix that are +1 or -1 away in absolute value from each row

As an example below, the first row of mat is **3,3**. Therefore, *myfun* will output a list with rows **2** and **3** being closest to row 1, but not row **5**, which is +2 away.

```
library(microbenchmark)
dim(mat)
[1] 1000    2
head(mat)
      x y
[1,]  3 3
[2,]  3 4
[3,]  3 2
[4,]  7 3
[5,]  4 4
[6,] 10 1

output
[[1]]
[1] 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
integer(0)

[[5]]
integer(0)

[[6]]
integer(0)


microbenchmark( myfun(mat), times =  100) #mat of 1000 rows
#    Unit: milliseconds
#             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#    myfun(mat) 89.30126 90.28618 95.50418 90.91281 91.50875 180.1505   100

microbenchmark( myfun(mat), times =  100) #mat of 10,000 rows
#    Unit: seconds
#             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#    myfun(layout.old) 5.912633 5.912633 5.912633 5.912633 5.912633 5.912633     1
```

This is what *myfun* looks like

```
myfun = function(x){
    doo <- function(j) {
        j.mat <- matrix(rep(j, length = length(x)), ncol = ncol(x), byrow = TRUE)
        j.abs <- abs(j.mat - x)
        return(which(rowSums(j.abs) == 1))
    }
    return(apply(x, 1, doo))
}
```

Comment: there are are few posts about faster / more efficient `dist`ance calculations that may be helpful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190214/dist-function-with-large-number-of-points , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668675/recalculating-distance-matrix , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138179/parallel-distance-matrix-in-r , http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Efficient-distance-calculation-on-big-matrix-td4633598.html . Which to use will depend on the, unstated, size of your data

Comment: shouldn't `output[[2]] = 1, 5` and `output[[5]] = 2`?

Comment: Cool, you listed your version of a `dist` function! However, there was no attempt to translate it into C++. So, we cannot really help you out as StackOverflow is not a free code translation service.

Comment: Removing the rcpp and armadillo tags.  The question has nothing to do with either, apart from the fact that OP is day-dreaming about somebody rewriting his code for him as @coatless pointed out.  Not likely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, I have a `base R` solution that is much faster than `myfun` provided by the OP.

```
myDistOne <- function(m) {
    v1 <- m[,1L]; v2 <- m[,2L]
    rs <- rowSums(m)
    lapply(seq_along(rs), function(x) {
        t1 <- which(abs(rs[x] - rs) == 1)
        t2 <- t1[which(abs(v1[x] - v1[t1]) <= 1)]
        t2[which(abs(v2[x] - v2[t2]) <= 1)]
    })
}
```

Here are some benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(9711)
m1 <- matrix(sample(50, 2000, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)   ## 1,000 rows
microbenchmark(myfun(m1), myDistOne(m1))
Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
    myfun(m1) 78.61637 78.61637 80.47931 80.47931 82.34225 82.34225     2   b
myDistOne(m1) 27.34810 27.34810 28.18758 28.18758 29.02707 29.02707     2  a 

identical(myfun(m1), myDistOne(m1))
[1] TRUE

m2 <- matrix(sample(200, 20000, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)  ## 10,000 rows
microbenchmark(myfun(m2), myDistOne(m2))
Unit: seconds
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
    myfun(m2) 5.219318 5.533835 5.758671 5.714263 5.914672 7.290701   100   b
myDistOne(m2) 1.230721 1.366208 1.433403 1.419413 1.473783 1.879530   100  a 

identical(myfun(m2), myDistOne(m2))
[1] TRUE
```

Here is a very large example:

```
m3 <- matrix(sample(1000, 100000, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2) ## 50,000 rows
system.time(testJoe <- myDistOne(m3))
   user  system elapsed 
 26.963  10.988  37.973 

system.time(testUser <- myfun(m3))
   user  system elapsed 
148.444  33.297 182.639 

identical(testJoe, testUser)
[1] TRUE
```

I'm sure there is a faster solution. Maybe by sorting the rowSums upfront and working from there could see an improvement (it could also get very messy).

## Update

As I predicted, working from a sorted rowSums is much faster (and uglier!)

```
myDistOneFast <- function(m) {
    v1 <- m[,1L]; v2 <- m[,2L]
    origrs <- rowSums(m)
    mySort <- order(origrs)
    rs <- origrs[mySort]
    myDiff <- c(0L, diff(rs))
    brks <- which(myDiff > 0L)
    lenB <- length(brks)
    n <- nrow(m)
    myL <- vector("list", length = n)

    findRows <- function(v, s, r, u1, u2) {
        lapply(v, function(x) {
            sx <- s[x]
            tv1 <- s[r]
            tv2 <- tv1[which(abs(u1[sx] - u1[tv1]) <= 1)]
            tv2[which(abs(u2[sx] - u2[tv2]) <= 1)]
        })
    }

    t1 <- brks[1L]; t2 <- brks[2L]
    ## setting first index in myL
    myL[mySort[1L:(t1-1L)]] <- findRows(1L:(t1-1L), mySort, t1:(t2-1L), v1, v2)
    k <- t0 <- 1L

    while (k < (lenB-1L)) {
        t1 <- brks[k]; t2 <- brks[k+1L]; t3 <- brks[k+2L]
        vec <- t1:(t2-1L)
        if (myDiff[t1] == 1L) {
            if (myDiff[t2] == 1L) {
                myL[mySort[vec]] <- findRows(vec, mySort, c(t0:(t1-1L), t2:(t3-1L)), v1, v2)
            } else {
                myL[mySort[vec]] <- findRows(vec, mySort, t0:(t1-1L), v1, v2)
            }
        } else if (myDiff[t2] == 1L) {
            myL[mySort[vec]] <- findRows(vec, mySort, t2:(t3-1L), v1, v2)
        }
        if (myDiff[t2] > 1L) {
            if (myDiff[t3] > 1L) {
                k <- k+2L; t0 <- t2
            } else {
                k <- k+1L; t0 <- t1
            }
        } else {k <- k+1L; t0 <- t1}
    }

    ## setting second to last index in myL
    if (k == lenB-1L) {
        t1 <- brks[k]; t2 <- brks[k+1L]; t3 <- n+1L; vec <- t1:(t2-1L)
        if (myDiff[t1] == 1L) {
            if (myDiff[t2] == 1L) {
                myL[mySort[vec]] <- findRows(vec, mySort, c(t0:(t1-1L), t2:(t3-1L)), v1, v2)
            } else {
                myL[mySort[vec]] <- findRows(vec, mySort, t0:(t1-1L), v1, v2)
            }
        } else if (myDiff[t2] == 1L) {
            myL[mySort[vec]] <- findRows(vec, mySort, t2:(t3-1L), v1, v2)
        }
        k <- k+1L; t0 <- t1
    }

    t1 <- brks[k]; vec <- t1:n
    if (myDiff[t1] == 1L) {
        myL[mySort[vec]] <- findRows(vec, mySort, t0:(t1-1L), v1, v2)
    }

    myL
}
```

The results are not even close. `myDistOneFast` is over 100x faster than the OP's original `myfun` on very large matrices and also scales well. Below are some benchmarks:

```
microbenchmark(OP = myfun(m1), Joe = myDistOne(m1), JoeFast = myDistOneFast(m1))
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
     OP 57.60683 59.51508 62.91059 60.63064 61.87141 109.39386   100
    Joe 22.00127 23.11457 24.35363 23.87073 24.87484  58.98532   100
JoeFast 11.27834 11.99201 12.59896 12.43352 13.08253  15.35676   100

microbenchmark(OP = myfun(m2), Joe = myDistOne(m2), JoeFast = myDistOneFast(m2))
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
     OP 4461.8201 4527.5780 4592.0409 4573.8673 4633.9278 4867.5244   100
    Joe 1287.0222 1316.5586 1339.3653 1331.2534 1352.3134 1524.2521   100
JoeFast  128.4243  134.0409  138.7518  136.3929  141.3046  172.2499   100

system.time(testJoeFast <- myDistOneFast(m3))
user  system elapsed 
0.68    0.00    0.69   ### myfun took over 100s!!!
```

To test equality, we have to sort each vector of indices. We also can't use `identical` for comparison as `myL` is initialized as an empty list, thus some of the indices contain `NULL` values (these correspond to `integer(0)` in the result from `myfun` and `myDistOne`).

```
testJoeFast <- lapply(testJoeFast, sort)
all(sapply(1:50000, function(x) all(testJoe[[x]]==testJoeFast[[x]])))
[1] TRUE

unlist(testJoe[which(sapply(testJoeFast, is.null))])
integer(0)
```

Here is an example with 500,000 rows:

```
set.seed(42)
m4 <- matrix(sample(2000, 1000000, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)
system.time(myDistOneFast(m4))
   user  system elapsed 
  10.84    0.06   10.94
```

Here is an overview of how the algorithm works:

1. Calculate rowSums
2. Order the rowSums (i.e. returns the indices from the original vector of the sorted vector)
3. Call [diff](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diff.html)
4. Mark each non-zero instance
5. Determine which indices in small range satisfy the OP's request
6. Use the ordered vector calculated in `2` to determine original index

This is much faster than comparing one rowSum to all of the rowSum every time.